# Using ARC in LLVM without Obj-C

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, llvm

Is it possible to use the ARC feature of LLVM to do the reference counting for my own language that I am implementing (without targeting Obj-C as the backend)

This would be very helpful, as the amount of effort for writing the GC would be greatly reduced

Comment: ARC is no traditional garbage collector. It does not traverse ownership graphs and does not find cycles.

Comment: I can only second @NikolaiRuhe. If you want GC, use GC. Reference counting can serve as as starting point for this (there are extensions which can handle cycles, though I haven't studied them in depth and haven't seen implementations yet), but you probably can't reasonably to re-use the highly ObjC-specific implementation in LLVM. If you want GC, maybe use Boehm for prototyping and add a proper mark & sweep GC later on.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe the point (for me) is that have some form of ref-counting in place means I don't have to worry about running out of memory when bootstrapping the compiler + standard library, before writing the garbage collector.

Comment: Also take note that reference counting itself is not really done by ARC but is implemented in Foundation (?). ARC just automatically inserts increments and decrements to the existing reference counting architecture. Also, ARC is coupled tightly to Objective-C as it derives its rules from method name families.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, no.

ARC is a compiler front-end feature and not a runtime facility. Not a LLVM back-end part.

Conceptually, ARC is an automatic generation of manual reference counting code by Objective-C ownership rules and conventions. Actual RC is managed by objc runtime.